How to generate oauth2 key(bearer ya29.) in kotlin?
I want to use FCM HTTP v1 in my app. As I know, I need to get OAuth2 access token to make the following function work. (i.e.  val "bearer" in the following function)
fun trypostsuccess(target: String, title: String, des: String){
        var timenow = Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
        var body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"),"{\"message\": {\"notification\": {\"title\": \"${title} (${timenow})\",\"body\": \"${des}\" },\"token\": \"${target}\"}}")

        val bearer = "ya29.a0Ad52N3__nJYFw-uXtVHHbhNKbHu-l2x_yduWntgFVd-ooh_o9mtFpwr1DLkRIhMDomUby1008OgqWRujPRPkrnmEPulv03Bxk4REP1krpfnevfepDTMs9frApgcpVVdt1lLg10htYHYdsaZVmHe6N0QPF5C7_uoXV3J6aCgYKARcSARASFQHGX2MixrfNEQc70YrHDy1eecDU9g0171"
        //ya29 20240402 212100
        val reqx = Request.Builder()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+bearer)
                .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/574244286072/messages:send")
                .post(body)
                .build()

        OkHttpClient().newCall(reqx).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, responses: Response) {
                when {
                    responses.code() == 200 -> {Log.i("trpost","Pass")}
                    !responses.isSuccessful -> Log.e(
                        "Server Error",
                        "${responses.code()} ${responses.message()}"
                    )
                    else -> Log.e("Other Error", "${responses.code()} ${responses.message()}")
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Log.e("Query fail", "$e")
            }
        })

    }

As I know, this OAuth2 access token is short-term which expires after 1 hour. In app test, I can get this Oauth2 access token from Google Oauth2 playground, paste it manually. However, once the app published, it will no longer be valid. I need to build up a function according to the following link.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server
When I tried to implement the following in dependencies
dependencies {
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.2.0")
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0")

    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display")
}
    

which shows

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

It seems using Admin SDK is not worked for me at this instance, so I need to try another way to generate OAuth2 access token for my FCM project. When I surf in the internet, I can't get any feasible way to get OAuth2 access token.
Is there any way which I generate an OAuth2 access token in my kotlin app? Thanks for your help.
